# In R, how can I transform data from long to wide while dealing with repeated values for my identifying variable?

Tags: r, transform

I'm working with a dataset that looks roughly like this:

| ID | MeasureA | MeasureB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 7 | 10 |
| 4 | 8 | 4 |
| 4 | 9 | 6 |
| 5 | 19 | 11 |
| 5 | 11 | 8 |
| 6 | 5 | 9 |

...

What I need is an output table that has each ID variable only once, and has as many columns for both Measure A and Measure B as are necessary. Consider that some IDs do not repeat, and the number of times they repeate are not always the same, as the example show.
The expected output table looks something like this:

| ID | MeasureA1 | MeasureA2 | MeasureA3 | MeasureB1 | MeasureB2 | MeasureB3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | NA | NA | 1 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 10 | 4 | NA | 0 | 3 | NA |
| 3 | 3 | NA | NA | 11 | NA | NA |
| 4 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 19 | 11 | NA | 11 | 8 | NA |
| 6 | 5 | NA | NA | 9 | NA | NA |

...

I've been stuck at this problem for some time. Can anyone help me do this in RStudio? Thanks!

I tried using the duplicate function to differentiate the repeated IDs and later perform a long-to-wide transform, but it didn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6),
  MeasureA = c(3, 10, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9, 19, 11, 5),
  MeasureB = c(1, 0, 3, 11, 10, 4, 6, 11, 8, 9)
)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(MeasureA:MeasureB) |> 
  group_by(ID, name) |> 
  mutate(name = paste0(name, row_number())) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#> # Groups:   ID [6]
#>      ID MeasureA1 MeasureB1 MeasureA2 MeasureB2 MeasureA3 MeasureB3
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1         3         1        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 2     2        10         0         4         3        NA        NA
#> 3     3         3        11        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 4     4         7        10         8         4         9         6
#> 5     5        19        11        11         8        NA        NA
#> 6     6         5         9        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With base R, you can first use `ave` to assign indices within `ID`s, and then `reshape` the dataframe to wide format, e.g.,

```
reshape(
  transform(
    df,
    g = ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq_along)
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "ID",
  timevar = "g"
)
```

and you will obtain

```
   ID MeasureA.1 MeasureB.1 MeasureA.2 MeasureB.2 MeasureA.3 MeasureB.3
1   1          3          1         NA         NA         NA         NA
2   2         10          0          4          3         NA         NA
4   3          3         11         NA         NA         NA         NA
5   4          7         10          8          4          9          6
8   5         19         11         11          8         NA         NA
10  6          5          9         NA         NA         NA         NA
```